# Typo in Wikipedia?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

I took a quick glance at the wikipedia article untitled "Selberg class", and I found quite a weird statement in it, namely that Selberg's conjectures imply that $F\in\mathcal{S}$ is primitive if and only if $d_{F}=1$. Shouldn't it be $n_{F}=1$?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the appropriate first action is to ask this question on the corresponding discussion page on Wikipedia, rather than first bringing the discussion to MO. 

Comment: To play devil's advocate: for what sounds like a rather technical matter, which one doesn't know the answer to, but which one has good reason to believe *some* expert who reads MO might know with relative ease... isn't that one of the desired uses of MO?

Comment: (last comment addressed to Ryan)

Comment: Yemon, I suppose you're right, but in this case, the author already knows the answer.

Comment: @Yemon: I don't think we should be encouraging people to break the norms of other forums.   Moreover, your devil's advocacy applies just as well to homework as Wikipedia pages.  Simply because MO is convienient does not mean it should be the first place you go to to answer any mathematical question. 

Comment: @Ryan, with all due respect, my remarks were deliberately meant to exclude the case of homework. Hence the words "rather technical matter". I confess to ignorance of Wikipedia's norms. 

Comment: I am the person answering: while I still do not disagree with the first comment, on reflection and in view of Yemon Choi's comment, I now think that mainly/only the formulation made this question a bit problematic. Had it just asked for confirmation/a reference for the fact, as a maths question, and given the wikipedia-typo not at all or just as source for confusion and motivation, I think there would have been less discussion. But, I guess, the question served its purpose, so perhaps no need for further discussion. 

Comment: Putting it on the Wikipedia article's discussion page could mean a long wait for an answer.  Sometimes putting it on the mathematics WikiProject's [discussion page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:WikiProject_Mathematics) is appropriate.  That page seems to get more traffic than nearly all of the many thousand's of WikiProjects' discussion pages.  Another place on Wikipedia that is sometimes appropriate is [the mathematics reference desk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Mathematics).

Answer (score 2):

Not totally disagreeing with the comment; but, I just looked this up, so I can as well answer.

Yes, you are right.

In the paper

> Kaczorowski and Perelli, The Selberg class: A survey, in Number Theory in Progress (Zakopane-Kościelisko, 1997), Vol. 2, de Gruyter, Berlin, 1999, 953--992

one can find the assertion you mention (with $n_f$) as Theorem 4.2.ii, and Theorem 4.2 is attributed to

> Conrey and Gosh, On the Selberg class of Dirichlet series: small degrees,
>   Duke J. Math. 72 (1993), 673--693.

Comment: So could someone who understands this please fix the Wikipedia page? After all, having the information here that there's a mistake there doesn't help unless it actually gets acted on. Thanks!

Comment: It's been fixed.